# Mutate a column considering only a subset of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having some troubles about data manipulation with `dpylr`. Basically I have a dataset like this:

```
test <- data.frame(
  var1 = rnorm(10, 10, 3),
  var2 = rnorm(10, 20, 6),
  var3 = c(rnorm(7, 20, 6), NA, NA, NA)
)

> test
        var1      var2     var3
1   8.882003 16.222680 21.46382
2   7.220067 22.296354 22.88066
3  11.060342 27.886035 16.01724
4   6.165811  6.320757 20.76175
5   7.599280 29.168573 11.54408
6   7.807514 19.811270 15.10216
7   6.518541 28.733050 17.15341
8   7.601128 13.063873       NA
9   5.992121 24.232977       NA
10  6.510580 24.478872       NA
```

`var3` hypothetically is computed as `var1 + var2` so I would like to fill NA values in `var3` computing the `var1 + var2` (or whatever operation using **columns**) but only for rows with NA values. How can I do?

Comment: With [tag:data.table] this would be the solution: `library(data.table); setDT(test)[is.na(var3), var3 := var 1 + var2]`

Comment: or with base R: `ix <- is.na(test$var3); test$var3[ix] <- rowSums(test[ix, 1:2])`

Answer (score 2):

```
... %>% mutate(var3=ifelse(is.na(var3), var1 + var2, var3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
test$var3 <- ifelse(is.na(test$var3), test$var1 + test$var2, test$var3)
```